# Parsing pipe-delimited lines in C

Tags: c, scanf

The text file I'm loading is in the commented section of the code below. I'm unable to get `sscanf()` to work like I think it should. There has to be a way that is nearly this elegant without having to go through each character using pointers, for loops, etc.

```
//Apex City Hotel|4|61 Grassmarket|Edinburgh|EH1
//Hilton Edinburgh Airport|4|Edinburgh International Airport|Edinburgh|EH12
//Novotel Edinburgh Centre|4|80 Lauriston Place|Edinburgh|EH3
//Premier Inn Haymarket|3|1 Morrison Link|Edinburgh|EH3
//Premier Inn Lauriston Place|3|82 Lauriston Place|Edinburgh|EH3
//Premier Inn Leith|3|51-53 Newhaven Place - Leith|Edinburgh|EH6
//Sheraton Grand Hotel & Spa|5|1 Festival Square|Edinburgh|EH3
//The Caledonian|5|Princess Street|Edinburgh|EH1
//The Glasshouse|5|2 Greenside Place|Edinburgh|EH1
//The Hilton Edinburgh Grosvenor|4|Grosvenor Street|Haymarket|Edinburgh|EH12
```

Code:

```
int main(void)
{
    char inputArray[NUM_OF_CHARACTERS];
    FILE *fp = fopen("OpenChampionshipHotels.txt", "r");
    fgets(inputArray, NUM_OF_CHARACTERS, fp);    

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error Reading File\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // copy lines from text file to array
    char hotelName[lineCount][NUM_OF_CHARACTERS];
    char hotelRating[lineCount][NUM_OF_CHARACTERS];
    char hotelStreetAddress[lineCount][NUM_OF_CHARACTERS];
    char hotelCity[lineCount][NUM_OF_CHARACTERS];
    char hotelPostalCode[lineCount][NUM_OF_CHARACTERS];

    lineCount = 0;
    while(fgets(inputArray, sizeof(inputArray), fp) != NULL)
    {
        sscanf(inputArray, "%[^|]|%[^|]|%[^|]|%[^|]|%s",
               hotelName[lineCount],
               hotelRating[lineCount],
               hotelStreetAddress[lineCount],
               hotelCity[lineCount],
               hotelPostalCode[lineCount] );

        printf("%s\n", hotelName[lineCount]);
        printf("%s\n", hotelRating[lineCount]);
        printf("%s\n", hotelStreetAddress[lineCount]);
        printf("%s\n", hotelCity[lineCount]);
        printf("%s\n", hotelPostalCode[lineCount]);

        lineCount++;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"I'm unable to get sscanf() to work like I think it should."*  How do you think it should work? What results are you getting?  What have you tried to debug or fix the problem?  (Question asking **101**)

Comment: `"Error Reading File"` is the canonical example of a useless error message.  Include the filename and the reason!! `man perror`

Comment: Note that you should check the return value from `sscanf()` to be sure the line was in the correct format.  If you ever get a full postcode (EH3 9JX), you'll need to fix the `%s` conversion specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `sscanf()` there is fine.  Your problem is just that you're using `lineCount` to declare the size of your arrays, which is presumably a global variable and therefore zero at that point.

Define a constant `NUM_OF_LINES` and use that instead:

```
char hotelName[NUM_OF_LINES][NUM_OF_CHARACTERS];
char hotelRating[NUM_OF_LINES][NUM_OF_CHARACTERS];
char hotelStreetAddress[NUM_OF_LINES][NUM_OF_CHARACTERS];
char hotelCity[NUM_OF_LINES][NUM_OF_CHARACTERS];
char hotelPostalCode[NUM_OF_LINES][NUM_OF_CHARACTERS];
```

(You should also check that `sscanf()` returned 5, to catch lines without the right number of fields, and add `lineCount < NUM_OF_LINES` to the `while()` condition).